# SlackBot - get input from user

Tags: python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I am writing now a slack bot that will be able to perform automated actions and return the value to the client end-user.

My flow:

1. A client sends a message to the bot
2. The bot responds with interactive message that contains buttons. Each button is kind of "Category".
3. According to the selected category, another interactive message is sent to the user with another buttons.
4. At this stage, according to the selected action, I need to get at least one input from the end-user (for example: ask for a string to search for in my DB).

I am wondering what will be the best practice solution for getting this input from the user?
I can't get it as a regular message since I don't have any option to correlate it with the selected action, and I can't find an input text field in the interactive messages that Slack offers (maybe a dialog?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [Slack Dialog](https://api.slack.com/dialogs) is the right approach to get text input from the user in a workflow.

Your interactive message request from Slack will contain a `trigger_id`, which you can use to initiate the Dialog.

Note that a Dialog can also contain drop down boxes and up to 5 input fields. So instead of providing buttons to choose the categories, you may also opt for using drop down menus and having everything in one dialog.